# What Are Guilds of Ravnica Guild Kits?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is a Guilds of Ravnica guild kit? Are they legal to use? What's special about them over other preconstructed product?

Comment: "Worth it" isn't a question we can answer as it's entirely personal to your own circumstances

Comment: "What is a Ravnica Guild kit" is a reasonable question.  Everything else is opinion based.

Comment: [The 2nd Google result for *Guilds of Ravnica guild kit*](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Guilds_of_Ravnica/Guild_Kits) explains what they are. [The 1st Google result](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/guilds-ravnica-guild-kits-2018-09-25) lists specific cards.

Comment: Do NOT edit an existing question you have asked to make it a completely different question. It is very easy to ask a new question here, but editing an existing question to make it a new question makes all the answers and comments given towards the original question invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guild kits from Guilds of Ravnica(GRN) and Ravnica Allegiance(RNA) are preconstructed 60 card decks using cards for that guild, however the cards are not all standard legal. This is the third time Magic has visited Ravnica, and cards that were in older visits are also included in the guild kits, such as [Tolsimir Wolfblood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTolsimir%20Wolfblood%5d) from Ravnica: City of Guilds, the first visit, or [Boros Reckoner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoros%20Reckoner%5d) from Gatecrash in the second visit.

The old cards and basic lands in the guild kit have the guild's symbol as the set symbol, GRN and RNA cards have the matching set symbol, they are all updated to the current border frame style, including the new legendary style and those that were originally watermarked with the guild symbol still are. Even the basic lands are specially marked as from that guild kit, with symbolism in their text box watermark that matches the guild, but is not the common watermark for guild cards. The five main cards of the kits (one each) also are foil and have new art, these cards are [Etrata, the Silencer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtrata%2c%20the%20Silencer%5d), [Niv-Mizzet, the Firemind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNiv-Mizzet%2c%20the%20Firemind%5d), [Izoni, Thousand-eyed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIzoni%2c%20Thousand-eyed%5d), [Aurelia, the Warleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%2c%20the%20Warleader%5d) and [Trostani, Slesnya's Voice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrostani%2c%5d%2b%5bSlesnya%27s%5d%2b%5bVoice%5d) in GRN and [Isperia, Supreme Judge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIsperia%2c%20Supreme%20Judge%5d), [Teysa, Orzhov Scion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeysa%2c%20Orzhov%20Scion%5d), [Rakdos, Lord of Riots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRakdos%2c%20Lord%20of%20Riots%5d), [Ruric Thar, the Unbowed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRuric%20Thar%2c%20the%20Unbowed%5d) and [Zegana, Utopian Speaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZegana%2c%20Utopian%20Speaker%5d) for RNA.

The sets also include a spin down die with the symbol as the 20, a 3" round sticker of the symbol of that guild, a 1.25" round metal pin with the symbol of that guild, and a cardboard deckbox with the guild symbol on the corner. All these are in the guild's colors.

[image: Izzet Island]